# Single and double-edge expressions (Verilog)

Tags: logic, verilog, hdl

I'm trying to describe a SN74ALS193 element, it's a **4-bit up-n-down binary counter**. The truth table is:

```
R   C   In   Dec

H   X   X   X
L   L   X   X
L   H   H   H
L   H   pe  H
L   H   H   pe

- In - increment (counting up)
- Dec - decrement (counting down)
- pe - positive edge
```

A positive pulse at the 'R' input resets the output of the counter (Q) to 0000. 'C' is the enable signal.

My code is:

```
module ic_1533ie7(R, C, In, Dec, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, CR, BR, D1, D2, D3, D4);

input D1, D2, D3, D4, Dec, In, C, R;
output Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, CR, BR;

wire [1:4] D;
reg [1:4] Q;

assign D = {D1, D2, D3, D4};
assign {Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4} = Q;

always @(R or C or posedge In or posedge Dec)
begin
if (R)
   Q = 0;
else if (C == 0)
   Q = D;
else if (In)
   Q <= Q + 1;
else if (Dec)
   Q <= Q - 1;
end 
endmodule
```

Quartus doesn't like my 'always' string (single and double-edge expressions are not permitted). So, how I supposed to describe this gate? Also, I don't understand, is it either a latch or it's an edge-triggered element?

Please, help

Comment: I don't understand the truth table. What are inputs, what are outputs? What are `R` and `C`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 A positive pulse at the 'R' input resets the output of the counter (Q) to 0000. 'C' is the enable signal.

Comment: Where is the `clock` for your design? For synthesis, you can't put anything in the sensitivity list, because otherwise the synthesizer will not interpret it correctly and may give some error

Comment: @KaranShah I'm not synthesizing this, I'm trying to put this element from schematic diagram to Quartus. There is no clock signal on the schematic diagram.

Comment: Can you please share the schematic as well here?

Comment: @KaranShah  http://www.datasheet-pdf.ru/1533/1533IE7-2.png

Answer (score 3):

Synthesizers want always blocks in one of two flavors:

- No `posedge` or `negedge`: This will synthesize to either combinational or level-sensitive latching logic depending how it is coded.
- 1 to 3 `posedge` or `negedge`. There must be one clocking signal (clocking signal cannot be referenced anywhere else in the always block). Depending on the supported cells, 0 to 2 asynchronous reset/preset. Asynchronous reset/preset have different set of rules to be synthesizable (such as as the assignments must be constants value). I will not go into detail because FPGA's have limited edge-tiggered flops with asynchronous reset/preset. Change your documentation for what is supported.

As toolic mentioned, the schematics is in the datasheet. Use it as a references for your RTL. To model the SN74ALS193 properly you are going to need 3 to 6 always blocks (maybe or less depending how you structure it and whether or not you use `assign` statements).

Comment: Are multiple 'always' blocks permitted in Verilog?

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln Yes!

Comment: By the way, I can't figure out the key point of this circut, there is NO a clock signal, thus this element doesn't apply to sequental logic. But, as you can see, there are 'pe' symbols in the truth table (and datasheet too) for 'In' and 'Dec' signals. How can this be?

Comment: I looked briefly at the schematic a while ago. Looked like the clock was generated by ANDing `In` and `Dec`.